# how to set the position of the placeholder of a placeholder in swift programatically ?

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

I am trying to create the following registration form . I cant set the space between the textfield image and the placeholder text . I've tried the following :

```
Email_text.placeholderRect(forBounds: CGRect(x: 10, y: 0 , width: 60, height: 50))
```

any idea how can I fix this ? 
Thanks [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like this, an extension for `UITextField`

```
extension UITextField {

    func setTextIconAndPlaceholder(icon: UIImage, placeholder: String) {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = icon
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
        let view = UIView()
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 2, width: 25, height: 25)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        self.leftView = view
        self.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
        self.placeholder = placeholder
    }

}
```

Comment: I am actually doing the exact same thing . just that in my extension I only set the image and I set the placeholder separately . But my question is how to put some specific distance between them :)

Comment: Here i am giving size 25 for view, and adding image view as subview which size is 20. So you will automatically have distance between the image and textfield. Just try this, it will work for sure (y)